# sp_addrolemember not working in Python

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, cgi, pyodbc

I am trying to add user permissions using this stored procedure:

```
exec sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, MYUSER
```

The database is MS SQL 2005 and within SQL Management Studio the stored procedure works correctly using my authorized windows login.

I created a simple HTML CGI website with Python as the scripting language using pyodbc. I also created a local user 'dataviewer' login that I used when pyodbc connects that has the following server role permissions the same as my windows login:

[image]

On the website I echo back the sql command that Python used and copy and paste the exact command in SQL SMS and the stored procedure works correctly.  It seems as though there is a security conflict somewhere but not sure what is happening becasue my windows login has the same server roles permission as the dataviewer login.

Comment: Please show your code using `pyodbc`. Are you committing the transaction?

Comment: All the checking I was doing and I forgot to commit the transaction. Thanks beargle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either commit the transaction with [`Connection.commit()`](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/Connection#commit), or set `autocommit=True` in connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the help, was so focused on something else that I forgot the simple stuff.